# Delaying file data for several minutes

Tags: c++, linux, bash, unix

On my machine, I have a file which is regenerated by an application every second - it contains different data each time, as it's based on some realtime data.

I would like to have a copy of this file, which would contain **what the original file contained 5 minutes ago**. Is this somehow easily achievable? I would be happy to do this using some BASH scripting magic, but adding some wise, memory efficient code to that original application (written in c++) would also satisfy me :)

Comment: can you simply store the data in a variable? or perhaps a temp file?

Comment: Is `while true; do cp file 5ago-file; sleep 300; done` What you're looking for?

Comment: Dave: If he needs to *always* be able to see what the file looked like 5 minutes ago, he'll need to copy the file every second and keep the past 5 minutes' worth of copies (i.e., 300 copies of files).

Comment: @Dave: Not exactly, I need that copy file to be also updated each second, yet with outdated data.

Comment: `file-"\`date\`"` could be the second arg, if that's what he wants.

Comment: Aah, you want the file to lag. How big is the file?

Comment: Lagging the file isn't impossible, but there are some tricks that might be a whole lot simpler. If you're just appending data to the end, why not just use a single file, timestamp all the entries, and read entries up until you reach 5 minutes ago? Or, if it's not appended sequentially, keep a map (in C++ terms) from records to timestamps. Does anything like that sound reasonable?

Comment: On the other hand, 300 50k files is 15MB, and we're talking 50k/s of I/O—much of which may be absorbed by the cache without even waiting on disk. On a phone or an embedded device that would be an unconscionable waste, but on a server, it's probably OK if it keeps your code sufficiently simpler.

Comment: @rafelcieslak Does the app correctly update the file's datestamp? Keep a running archive with tar, use tar's --number option to read the beginning of the archive and to delete copies older than you need. ( GNU tar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If disk space isn't an issue, you could make the program create a new file every second instead of writing to the same file. You would need a total of 300 files (`5 min * 60 sec/min)`. The file name to write to would be `$somename + timestamp() % 300`. That way, to get the file 5 minutes ago, you would just access the file `$somename + (timestamp()+1) % 300`.

Comment: Note: `%` means "modulo". Replace with whatever function provides this in bash. (I'm mainly a PHP programmer)

Comment: You can use the % operator inside a $(()) arithmetic block in bash. The full equivalent expression (assuming you have a "timestamp" function) would be "$somename$(($(timestamp)%300)), and the second expression is "$somename$((($(timestamp)+1)%300)).

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question with both [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) and [unix](/questions/tagged/unix). This answer only applies to Linux.

You may be able to use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) ([`inotifywait` `man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)) or [incron](http://incron.aiken.cz/) ([`incrontab(5)` `man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab)) to watch the directory and make copies of the files as they are closed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that, you need the space to hold each of the 300 (5*60) files. Since you indicate that the files are only about 50K in size, this is doable in 15MB memory (if you don't want to clutter your filesystem)

It should be as simple as: (something like)

```
struct {char* buf; size_t size} hist[300]; //initalize to all nulls.
int n = 0;
struct stat st;
for(;;sleep(1)){
    int ifd  = open("file", O_READ);
    int ofd = open("file-lag", O_WRITE);
    stat(ifd, &st);
    hist[n].size = st.st_size;
    if(hist[n].buf)
       free(hist[n].buf);
    buffer[n] = malloc(hist[n].size);
    read(ifd, hist.buf[n], hist[n].size);
    n = (n+1)%300;
    if(hist[n].buf)
        write(ofd, hist.buf[n], hist[n].size)
    close(ofd);
    close(ifd);
}
```